# How WappWolf gets notifications from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

As far as I know there's no way for server-side application to be notified by Google Drive that some file has been updated or uploaded.

But it seems the WappWolf somehow gets it, via some API - how it does that? ( see introduction video http://wappwolf.com/gdriveautomator )

Comment: I found an app that will notify you of changes to any type of Google Drive file, Checker Plus for Google Drive - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-google-d/pppfmbnpgflleackdcojndfgpiboghga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to currently get notifications from Google Drive. The best way is to poll the [changes feed of the Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#detecting_changes_to_resources) to see if a user's Drive files have changed, which files have changed, and to act upon those changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, to get notification from GoogleDrive, **only** when in Spreadsheet Format.
But it's a good start.

In the spreadsheet, go to Tools > Notification Rule. Here, set the rule that will notify your email when any changes is made to the form + data + spreadsheet,(whatever we called it).

From this starting point, you may define how you are going to be notified. For me, the simplest would be gmail apps notification within my android phone. The sky's truly the limit.